# Scaling ImageView object does not seem to change the clickable area

Tags: java, javafx

First of all, this is my first project in JavaFX, so if my general approach is wrong, I very much appreciate feedback on how else to implement this.

I'm trying to set up a hexagon grid of clickable tiles, similar to Settlers of Catan. I did this by creating a hex class that includes an imageview. For scaling purposes, these imageviews are scaled by a common parameter, where I tried both the .setScaleX/Y and setFitWidth/Heigth functions.
For what it matters, each hex is combined into a StackPane object and then all the hexes are combined into a Group.

To detect mouseclicks, I'm using the .setOnMouseClicked() function.

The problem I've been facing is that when the scaling parameter gets small, the imageviews seem to overlap their clickable areas. The graphic, however, scales properly. Since the setOnMouseClicked() function only responds non-transparent parts, this means there is no response when clicking on tiles overlapped by others.

How can I solve this problem? 
Is there a way to scale the clickable area using my global scale parameter? 
Can I somehow define the clickable area using some kind of path along the border?
Would it work to define a transparent hexagon shaped button and place on top of my image?

I tried using different approaches to scaling, such as setScaleX and setFitWidth.
I tried using setMaxSize() on the StackPane.
I tried using viewport and clip, but I don't think they do what I'm looking for.

```
public Hex(Point2D pos, double sizeScale){
    ...
    Image img = new Image( "images/hex.png" );
    m_size = new Point2D(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    m_image = new ImageView( img );
    ...
    m_image.setFitWidth(  m_sizeScale * m_size.getX() );
    m_image.setFitHeight( m_sizeScale * m_size.getY() );
    ...
}
```

Expected result:
Each hex is clickable, giving different responses based on which hex is clicked.
Actual result:
Hexes added before added hexes are not clickable if positioned to the right or below. (Anchor point is top-left)

Comment: The `ImageView` is a weird element when it comes to sizing/scaling. To save yourself the headache I would advice wrapping the `ImageView` in a `StackPane` (which is consistent regarding resizing etc.), and use that for event handling etc. (only dont forget to call `setMouseTransparent(true)` on the `ImageView`).

Comment: Also possible: Any type of `Region` with a `BackgroundImage`+`shape` property set to a polygon or a `Polygon` with an `ImagePattern` as fill...

Comment: Thanks, n247s, that worked out. Gonna avoid scaling imageviews then.
Thanks for the feedback, Fabian, gonna keep it in mind going forward :)